# DISTINCT, MAX and list value from join table

Tags: join, max, distinct

How to combine distinct and max within join table below?

Table_details_usage

```
UID | VE_NO |  START_MILEAGE  |  END_MILEAGE
------------------------------------------------ 
1   |  ASD  |    410000       |  410500  
2   |  JWQ  |    212000       |  212350 
3   |  WYS  |    521000       |  521150
4   |  JWQ  |    212360       |  212400 
5   |  ASD  |    410520       |  410600
```

Table_service_schedule

```
SID | VE_NO |  SV_ONMILEAGE  |  SV_NEXTMILEAGE
------------------------------------------------ 
1   |  ASD  |    400010      |  410010  
2   |  JWQ  |    212120      |  222120 
3   |  WYS  |    511950      |  521950
4   |  JWQ  |    212300      |  222300 
5   |  ASD  |    410510      |  420510
```

How to get display as below (only max value)?

Get Max value from Table_service_schedule (SV_NEXTMILEAGE) and Get Max value from Table_details_usage (END_MILEAGE)

```
SID | VE_NO |  SV_NEXTMILEAGE | END_MILEAGE 
-------------------------------------------- 
5   |  ASD  |    420510       | 410600
4   |  JWQ  |    222300       | 212400
3   |  WYS  |    521950       | 521150
```

Answer (score 0):

Something in the lines of:

```
SELECT 
    SID, 
    VE_NO, 
    SV_NEXTMILEAGE, 
    (select max(END_MILEAGE) from Table_details_usage d where d.VE_NO = s.VE_NO) END_MILEAGE 
FROM Table_service_schedule s 
WHERE SID = (SELECT max(SID) FROM Table_service_schedule s2 WHERE s2.VE_NO = s.VE_NO)
```

Probably could need to change the direct value ov SV_NEXTMILEAGE to max as well if the id:s aren't in order...